# Use Google as OAuth 2 server (Android + custom REST server)

Tags: android, oauth

I would like to do the following:

- Have an Android application which uses the `AccountManager` to get an auth token from the Google account the user picks (I would use the [getAuthToken](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#getAuthToken(android.accounts.Account,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle,%20boolean,%20android.accounts.AccountManagerCallback%3Candroid.os.Bundle%3E,%20android.os.Handler)) method, I suppose the eventual token in the returned `Bundle` is a `String`).
- Make a request to my custom remote REST server (Spring Boot) and send the token with it in the `Authorization` header.
- Have the server take the request, extract the token and check with some Google server whether it is valid for the account and the information for authorization checks. (I would somehow need to get the email address here - is it possible?)

Does this make sense? Is the `AccountManager` supposed to be used this way? Do you know of any tutorials/samples which do just this?

I am planning on reading the Google documentation, but as it i quite long I would like to know that at least I'm headed in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have documented is widely accepted as the best way to use token based authentication via a Web API.

Account manager gets your app the token to identify your user. You then pass the token to the server to identify the user on the server. The server then verifies the token with your auth provider to ensure that the user is real.

You can follow the tutorials on https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/ for your purposes

Comment: With a token from the server, you can then get all the user information that the app is authorised to access